# Calculating the limit $ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{4} \cdot \sin(4 \pi/n) $.

Tags: limits

I would like to calculate
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{n}{4} \sin \left(\frac{4 \pi}{n} \right)$$

Clearly this is a limit of the type $\infty \cdot 0$, so I'm thinking there is probably some way to turn it to $\infty / \infty$ or $0 / 0 $ and then use L'Hopital but I can't think of any such trick. I cannot think of a way to do it without L'Hoptial either. Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: If you can prove that 
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1,
$$
then you are almost done by writing $x=4/n$ and letting $n\to \infty$.

Comment: Not quite "done" but mostly done. There is the issue of the $\pi$...

Comment: Right, you've still to deal with the constant.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**: Write your expression as
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{\sin(\pi(4/n))}{4/n}$$ and make use of the fact that
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{\sin(ax)}{x} = a$$

Answer (score 1):

you can use the taylor of $\sin(4\pi/n)$ as follow
$$y=x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}+\cdots$$
$$y=\frac{4\pi}{n}-\frac{(4\pi)^3}{3!n^3}+\frac{(4\pi)^5}{5!n^5}+\cdots$$
so
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\frac{n}{4}(\frac{4\pi}{n}-\frac{(4\pi)^3}{3!n^3}+\frac{(4\pi)^5}{5!n^5}+\cdots)=\pi$$

Comment: PS: \cdots ($\cdots$) would be more appropriate here.

Comment: big-O notation makes this nicer

Answer (score 0):

We know $\sin \theta = \theta + \mathcal{O}(\theta^3)$ for $\theta \approx 0$. Then it becomes $\frac{n}{4}\frac{4\pi}{n} + \mathcal{O}(n^{-2})$.

O notation can be handy.